# Column1+Column2 on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to ask on how to do this in google spreadsheet without using script. Apologies for the title, it is my first time posting a question here. Thank you very much :)

**Example:**

```
| 1 | A | A-1 |
| 2 | B | A-2 |
| 3 | C | A-3 |
|   |   | B-1 |
|   |   | B-2 |
|   |   | B-3 |
|   |   | C-1 |
|   |   | C-2 |
|   |   | C-3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `1` is in A1, drag down from Row1:

```
=OFFSET(B$1,INT((ROW()-1)/3),)&"-"&OFFSET(A$1,MOD((ROW()-1),3),)
```